# jq: filter result by value (contains) is very slow

Tags: json, substring, jq

I am trying to use jq to filter a large number of JSON files and extract the ids of each object who belong to a specific domain, as well as the full URL within that domain. Here's a sample of the data:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "completeness": 5,
            "dcLanguageLangAware": {
                "def": [
                    "de"
                ]
            },
            "edmIsShownBy": [
                "https://gallica.example/image/2IC6BQAEGWUEG4OP7AYBDGIGYAX62KZ6H366KXP2IKVAF4LKY37Q/presentation_images/5591be60-01fc-11e6-8e10-fa163e091926/node-3/image/SBB/Berliner_Börsenzeitung/1920/02/27/F_065_098_0/F_SBB_00007_19200227_065_098_0_001/full/full/0/default.jpg"
            ],
            "id": "/9200355/BibliographicResource_3000117730632",
            "type": "TEXT",
            "ugc": [
                false
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Bigger sample here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0s0zjtxe01mecjc/AoQhRn%2B56KDm5AJJPwEvOTIwMDUyMC9hcmtfXzEyMTQ4X2JwdDZrMTAyNzY2Nw%3D%3D.json?dl=0

I can extract both ids and URL which contains the string "gallica" using the following command:

```sh
jq '[ .items[] | select(.edmIsShownBy[] | contains ("gallica")) |  {id: .id, link: .edmIsShownBy[] }]'
```

However, i have more than 28000 JSON files to process and it is taking a large amount of time (around 1 file per minute). I am processing the files using bash with the command:

```sh
find . -name "*.json" -exec cat '{}' ';' | jq '[ .items[] | select(.edmIsShownBy[] | contains ("gallica")) |  {id: .id, link: .edmIsShownBy[] }]'
```

I was wondering if the slowness is due by the instruction given to jq, and if it is the case, is there a faster way to filter a string contained in a chosen value? Any ideas?

Comment: `find . -name '*.json' -exec cat {} + | jq '[.items[] | select(.edmIsShownBy[0] | index("gallica")) | {id, link: .edmIsShownBy[0]}]'` would be a little bit faster

Comment: The fact that there are two occurrences of `edmIsShownBy[]` in the query suggests that your query might not correspond to your intentions or expectations. Please elaborate on the requirements.

Comment: The pastebin sample is only 60KB, which seems rather small, and is processed very quickly by jq (0.035 sec on my computer)  How large is the file that takes 1 minute?

Comment: pastebin had some length limits. I now edited and added a link to one of the file in dropbox. Files are not big (around 450kb), but it is indeed slow, that is why I thought I am doing something wrong with it

Comment: For the record, the Dropbox sample is ~463KB and the query against it once takes about 0.05s (u+s, including the startup time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be wise not to attempt to `cat` all the files at once; indeed, it would probably be best to avoid `cat` altogether.

For example, assuming program.jq contains whichever jq program you decide on (and there is nothing wrong with using `contains` here), you could try:

```
find . -name "*.json" -exec jq -f program.jq '{}' +
```

Using the non-standard + instead of ';' minimizes the number of times jq must be called, though the overhead of invoking jq is actually quite small. If your `find` does not support `+` and you wish to avoid calling jq once per file, then consider using [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs), or GNU `parallel` with the `—-xargs` option.

If you know the JSON files of interest are in the pwd, you could also speed up `find` by specifying `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: This solved the issue. It was not jq but cat which was slowing everything down. Without cat (and using maxdepth 1) it takes 10 minutes to process >28000 json files. thank you very much! I thought it was due by my inexperience with jq but it ends up I was just looking in the wrong place